# Real Analysis Mathematics sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Question (asked by James Blair- [Suppose $f: X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $c$ and $f(c)>0$. Prove that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258585/suppose-f-x-rightarrow-mathbbr-is-continuous-at-c-and-fc0-prove-tha))

Suppose $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at some $c\in X$. Suppose also that $f(c) > 0$. Prove that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$.

in which epsilon is taken to be $f(c)/2$ (the natural numbers are not bounded Archimedean property so you can always find a number greater).

But how would yo go about solving the above assertion if it was replaced by: $f(c) > 0$ and $f(x) > 0$ with $f(c) \geq 0$ and $f(x) \geq 0$, respectively?

Thanks

Comment: It wouldn't be true. Consider $f(x)=-x^2$ and $c=0$. Then $f(0)=0\ge 0$ but for all neighborhoods of $0$, $f$ takes on negative values.

Answer (score 0):

You can observe it in a very simple way.
since, according to you,
f(c)≥0
So, we can take f(c)=0

Now, draw any continious function whose graph lies on 3rd & 4th quadrants.

That means, for all x ,f(x) gives negative value.

Like,
for any c ,
You can take ,

f(x)= - (x-c)^2 .

It gives value f(x) <0 in any nbd of c.